# Display dictionary key,Value on a UILabel swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

Trying to figure out how to display an array of dictionary data key,value returning form a server as a json on a uilabel or textfield.

**Here is the dictionary**
[image: Here is the dictionary].

**I want it to be displayed like this**

[image: I want it to be displayed like this]

Comment: So what your specific problem is?

Comment: What do you have so far? Displaying JSON data is a **very** frequently asked question.

Comment: don't have much of a clue how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

I assume your JSON data is in this format:

```
let jsonColours = ["Colour": "Moss Green", "Fabric": "Cotton"...]
```

You can try running a `for/in` loop on the jsonColour:

```
 for data in jsonColour {
    let key = data.key //key value which is colour or fabric
    let value = data.value //value which would be moss green or cotton
 }
```